# How to show success message after validation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to valid some fields and I want to show success message **$('.alert-success').show();** after user entered all values.
I tried here **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshpattu/6s3nn/)** Now I am able to validate all fields but I don't know how to show success message if all fields are not null.
Html:

```
<div class="contentContainer">
    <div class="alert alert-success hide">Form submitted successfully</div>
                        <div id="basicInfo">
                            <div class="toggleContentInnerSec"> 
                             <div class="row-fluid">
                                 <div class="span7">

                                 <label>First Name</label> <br> 
                                 <p class="hide firstNameErrorMsg error">Please enter first name</p>
                                 <input type="text" name="borrowerBasicDetail.firstName" value="" id="addBorrowers_borrowerBasicDetail_firstName" class="access required" placeholder="Example: 'Sachin' " data-errormsg="firstNameErrorMsg"> <br>
                                 <label>Last Name</label> <br>
                                 <p class="hide lastNameErrorMsg error">Please enter last name</p> 
                                 <input type="text" name="borrowerBasicDetail.lastName" value="" id="addBorrowers_borrowerBasicDetail_lastName" class="access required" placeholder="Example: 'Tendulkar' " data-errormsg="lastNameErrorMsg"> <br>
                                 <label>Date Of Birth</label> <br> 
                                 <p class="hide birthDayErrorMsg error">Please enter date of birth</p>
                                 <input type="text" name="borrowerBasicDetail.age" value="" id="addBorrowers_borrowerBasicDetail_age" class="access required" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" data-errormsg="birthDayErrorMsg"> <br>

                             </div> 
                         </div>

                         </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row-fluid pull-left">
                             <div class="form-actions">
                                <a class="btn btn-success btn-large" id="tabOneSubmit">Submit</a>
                             </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
```

Script:

```
submit();

function submit(){
    $('#tabOneSubmit').click(function(){
        $('.required').each(function(){
            var element=$(this);
            var elementVal=$(this).val();
            var errorMsgId=element.attr('data-errorMsg');
            if(elementVal==''){
                $('.'+errorMsgId).show();
                element.addClass('errorField');
            }
            else{
                $('.'+errorMsgId).hide();
                element.removeClass('errorField');
                }
        });

    });
}
```

Comment: And what happened when you tried it ?

Comment: @PatsyIssa I am able to validate all fields but I don't know how to show success message if all fields are not null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution, just set a status variable.

```
submit();

function submit(){
    $('#tabOneSubmit').click(function(){
        var status=true;
        $('.required').each(function(){

            var element=$(this);
            var elementVal=$(this).val();
            var errorMsgId=element.attr('data-errorMsg');
            if(elementVal==''){
                $('.'+errorMsgId).show();
                element.addClass('errorField');
                status=false;
            }
            else{
                $('.'+errorMsgId).hide();
                element.removeClass('errorField');
                }
        });

        if(status) {
            $('.alert-success').show();
        }

    });
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ebQfm/)**

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#msg").html("Form was submitted");
```

Comment: Please describe in your answer, what was the problem, and how will this snippet solve it, to help others understand this answer

Answer (score 0):

First, using validator is a good thing but I suggest you check inputs in server side too, because it's easy to hack javascript code.

Secondly you need the encapsulate that your input fields via;

`<form method="POST or GET" action="foo.html"> </form>`

Then you can use jQuery **submit()** method to submit via javascript:

```
$(form).submit(function(){
    $('.alert-success').show();
    event.preventDefault(); // if you want to send data only, do not reload page.
});
```

*$(form)* can be like if form has id or class: `$('.myForm') , $('#myForm')`